# Why do Dassault Falcons only have one thrust reverser?

Tags: thrust-reverser, dassault-falcon

Using all 3 engines would slow it down much faster. No?

Comment: Thrust reversing engines are expensive. High on maintenance and the necessity to have so many reversers is not needed. If the speed falls below the acceptable levels, the jet drops like a ball. Dropping speed fast is dangerous. The fuselage will crack instantly or split because of such extreme temperature & pressure differences. These are just a few. I could think of a dozen more.

Comment: Because it doesn't need to slow down faster.

Comment: Not a dupe, but [this airliners.net thread may help](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=775767)

Comment: @kris what the...???

Comment: @Jpe61 agreed. "drop like a ball"? The plane is already on the ground...... By the way, can someone comment on the "high temperature/pressure difference" part? He might be onto something, but again, turbofan exhausts are *supposed* to not be very hot or high pressure

Comment: There is no reason the fuselage would crack or split because of thrust reversers. There is some huge misunderstanding here...

Answer (score 9):

As always, it is a trade-off.

On the positive side, thrust reversers allow you to slow down faster and reduce brake wear.

On the negative side, there are costs to install and maintain them. They add weight, which increases the required take-off length reduces the maximum payload and increases fuel consumption.

Dassault found the optimum for their design in one thrust reverser, others go with TR on all engines, none or optional.

Comment: "*On the negative side*" they is also a [risk of deployment in flight](https://safetyfirst.airbus.com/thrust-reverser-deployment-in-flight/) which needs careful mitigation and expensive [certification demonstration](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Thrust_Reversers:_Flight_Crew_Guidance).